# "Masonry" alignment of 2D or 3D objects of various sizes using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

i would like to take a collection of image planes, for example, or 3D objects of various sizes and instance them in a "masonry" style distribution pattern based that arranges each instance with equal (and tweakable) gaps between each instance.

Important that gap between is procedurally modifiable and that the scale of each object that is instanced is not changed when it is instanced.

Any ideas how I would go about accomplishing this?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: A simple 'Masonry' arrangement would be all in a row. You're obviously looking for more than that.. so the question is: what _is_  your constraint? ('Best Fit' is a mathematically hard problem) ..if the objects do not resize to fit.